# Can't make form.name.$invalid and form.name.$error.required work

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use AngularJS to validate a form, with the following code:

HTML

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
      <form name="ctrl.mForm" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="Name" required />
        <div ng-show="ctrl.mForm.Name.$invalid">Required</div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="send()" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.send = function () {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

[Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/YW772Cb0gWOL1mb2?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

I need to show a div when the input is empty (when the user clicks the submit button is enough), however nothing happens.

What is wrong with this code that it is unable to show the `<div>` when the input is empty?

Comment: The only missing thing I could see was `ng-model` your input is not mapped to any field. See the fork of your Plunker here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/IKUE9ZRjlHh06nRc?preview

Comment: The `<div...>Required</div>` still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controler code should have the variable for Name:

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.Name = "";
  vm.send = function () {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

and your input control should use that variable in ng-model

```
 <input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="Name" required />
```

Comment: The problem I'm asking is not related to the binding of Name variable, but the form validators not working

Comment: If you do this then the validator will work. I have tested with your plunk

Comment: You're right. In my project there was an additional problem, with more than one input with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

[Here i have updated the plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/DcF3ihFAFweyiDD1?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

You should use `ng-model` to validate using angular. i have updated that in plunker. and if you want to use default validation of html required field you should submit form using `ng-submit` direactive on form element

Comment: and @juliano-nunes-silva-oliveira i have disabled submit button until form is invalid that might help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the name of your form to "mForm". And on the div you want to show, you have to check if the name field is invalid and if the form got submitted.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
      <form name="mForm" novalidate>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" required />
        <div ng-show="mForm.name.$invalid && mForm.$submitted"">Required</div>
        <input type="submit" ng-click="send()" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

See this [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/iXskg99QTc8FXSdK?preview)